# VBA Sum of Fibonacci even numbers till sum < 100

Tags: excel, vba, fibonacci

I need your help regarding my homework.
The aim is to sum all even numbers from Fibonacci sequence till the sum reach < 100

I have created formula as below

```
Sub fibbo()

Dim sum As Long
Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
sum = 0

    Do While sum < 100

        sum = a + b
        a = b
        b = sum
        a = a + 1

    Loop

Range("A1").Value = sum

End Sub
```

The problem is that sum is over 100.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: remove the `While` from the `Do` and add `While sum + a < 100` to `Loop`.

Comment: Or just replace `Do While sum < 100` with `Do While a + b < 100`.

Comment: Both methods above return `88`

Comment: BTW, it does not only do even.  Every 3rd loop after the second returns an odd number for SUM.

Comment: You will also need to change the `a = a + 1` to `a = IIf(a = 0, 1, a)` the other is causing the sequence to not be correct.